# Personal pronoun before noun?

Tags: pronouns, antecedents

> 1. Before **Sarah** can board the bus, **she** needs to get some coins for the fare.
> 2. Before **she** can board the bus, **Sarah** needs to get some coins for the fare.

My questions are:

- Between the above two sentences, which is more correct?
- Can the pronoun come before the noun?
- Is there any rule defining this issue?
- Also, must the noun only be in the main clause?

Comment: THIS AIN'T A DUPE FOLKS! This questions asks about putting a pronoun before a noun in a sentence and if there are any rules about it. The other post only asks about two sentences that are both grammatical. The answer there also only talks about grammatical possibilities too and doesn't describe the rules. There are ungrammatical sentences that fit the OP's question and there are rules that are important for what's grammatical and what isn't too!!!

Comment: THIS AIN'T A DUPE FOLKS 2! In addition that question asks exclusively about the use of ***possessive*** pronouns. ***There's not a possessive pronoun in sight in this question here!***

Comment: @tchrist Hi there. Do you still believe this is a dupe of the linked-to Q? If not, any chance of a reopen vote?

Comment: Seem to be four questions here. Can you restrict yourself self to one?

Answer (score 10):

> a. Before Sarah<sub>i</sub> can board the bus, she<sub>i</sub>  needs to get some coins for the fare.
>
> b. Before she<sub>i</sub>  can board the bus, Sarah<sub>i</sub>  needs to get some coins for the fare.

Pronouns can:

1. Refer to anything in the speaker's and listener's environment that they are both aware of (they can be *exophoric*).
2. Refer to something previously mentioned within the sentence or within the conversation.
3. Refer to something higher up in the clause structure (so a pronoun in a subordinate clause can refer to a thing or person mentioned in the main, matrix clause).

Sentence (a) is fine because *she* co-refers backwards with *Sarah* which appears earlier in the sentence.

Sentence (b) is fine because *she* appears in a subordinate clause and refers to *Sarah* which is in the main clause.

Both types of sentence are perfectly acceptable and are very common in all types of speech and writing. Notice, however, that if none of conditions (1-3) hold, then *she* will not be able to co-refer with another common noun in the sentence. So we cannot have *she* in a main clause trying to co-refer with a later *Sarah* in a subordinate clause.

> c. *She<sub>i</sub>  needs to get some coins for the bus before Sarah<sub>i</sub>  can board it.

In sentence (c) *she* and *Sarah* cannot refer to the same person. This is because, firstly, *she* occurs **before** *Sarah*. Secondly, *Sarah* is subordinate, and *she* cannot refer to a noun in a lower clause. This sentence is not possibble.

Comment: Excellent. Concise and clear.

Comment: But lacking the supporting references of stature that ELU prizes.

Answer (score 1):

I find the two equally acceptable, regardless of whether "she" refers to the same person as "Sarah".  And grammatically, they are both expected to be acceptable, since in the first, the potential antecedent "Sarah" precedes "she", and in the second, "Sarah" commands "she".  "She" is commanded, because it is inside every clause that "Sarah" is inside:

> [S1 Before [S2 she can board the bus ], Sarah needs to get some coins for the fare.]

So "she" is inside clauses S1 and S2, but "Sarah" is only inside clause S1.

The command relation was introduced by Ronald Langacker in 1969.  It has led to much (not very productive) discussion since then.

Answer (score -1):

The pronoun is defined by the proper noun.  Therefore the proper noun should always be introduced prior to use of pronoun.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).